# Playing cards game

Tags: python, playing-cards

Here I have N number of cards numbered from 1 to N placed in a round table such that card 1 is between card 2 and card N . All the cards are initially upside down. The aim is to turn all the cards face up.

Let's say we touch a card i, touching the card i will turn the cards i-1,i,i+1 face up. similarly touching the card N will turn the cards N-1,N,1st card face up. 
I want to determine the minimum number of touches required to face up all the cards.

here is what i have been trying in python

```
q = int(raw_input())
if q==1 or q==2:
   print "1"
else:
   r = q%3
   l = q/3
   print r+l
```

q can be as big as 10^20.

What's wrong with above logic and In case the above logic is completely wrong what should be the correct approach.

Comment: Questions about algorithms, as opposed to questions about the mechanics of programming, have their own site. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in for guidelines on selecting the appropriate StackExchange site for a question.

Comment: ("What's wrong with above logic" should also be more clear -- a good question describes the **specific** behavior or error seen).

Comment: The logic is wrong because you only want ONE extra flip if q%3 is either 1 or 2, not 2 if q%3 is 2. For example with q = 5, that code'd print a 3, but you can obviously flip all cards in 2 turns

Comment: @EmilianoSorbello  Right! Got it. Thanks! :)

Comment: isnt this a hiring challenge question??

Answer (score 0):

It should be something along the lines of:

```
answer = q / 3 (+ 1 if q is not a multiple of 3)
```

So an easy way to neat way to code this'd be:

```
q = int (raw_input()) # This isn't safe since it causes Type Errors easily but... whatever...
print (q / 3) + 1 * (q % 3 > 0) # Because 1 * True = 1, 1 * False = 0
```

Comment: Thanks! What's the safe way for the first line ?

Comment: Convert into int inside of a try/except block, or checking first with your_string.isDigit(). You'd need some sort of while loop to ask for input infinitely until user writes a number