# Minimum number of steps to flip cards deck

Tags: algorithm, logic

This is a Contest problem not a home work.

Given `N` cards facing down, you have to flip all the `N` cards facing up. If you are flipping ith card then, i-1,i,i+1 will flipped. 
For eg: if N = 3, then minimum no of steps will be **1**.
Given N cards, we have to calculate the minimum no of steps to flip all the cards up.

Initially i thought it is kind of fibonacci, Let `N = 2,3,4` and minimum steps `Min = 1,1,4` but if `N = 6`, then the minimum steps will be **2**. I am struck here, Could anyone please help ?

Comment: You flip the cards 3 by 3 and you need to know how times you will have to flip?

Comment: Evil twin of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496917/minimum-flipping-of-the-cards and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496917/minimum-flipping-of-the-cards Neither have accepted answers, but may be useful.

Comment: It looks like the solution could be calculated with `N / 3 + (N % 3 ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: @higuaro it is what i think too

Comment: @Higuaro : no, if the N = 6, then ur formula is giving ans 3 but the minimum  steps is 2.

Comment: @vignesh, eh, nope, the formula returns 2 for N = 6

Comment: @higuaro: So, `(n + 2) / 3`, then?

Comment: @EduardoLeón nice one!

Answer (score 3):

The cases for N=1, 2, and 3 are easy.

For N = 3k, this is easy.  Just flip over k cards starting with the second one.

For N = 3k+1, first flip both cards on the ends, which flips over 4 cards.  Then we have 3k-3 cards left over, which is divisible by 3, which can be easily flipped in k-1 moves.

For N = 3k+2, first choose the first card, which flips 2 cards.  Now you have 3k cards left to flip, which is easily done in k flips.

Comment: i couldn't get 3K + 1.

Comment: both initial flips + k-1 = k+1

Comment: @Eduardo Leon : In the case N = 3K+1, flip both cards on the end , means first and last should be flipped, but if you flip the last card, then the first card will also be flipped again.

Comment: My mistake, forget to add another contion, If you flip the nth card then, n-1, n, 1 wil be flipped.

Comment: @vignesh: "if you flip the nth card then, n-1, n, 1 will be flipped" --> You *never* mentioned that!

Answer (score 2):

I gave an answer to a very similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483662/playing-cards-game?noredirect=1#comment50932808_31483662). The problem seems a little different at first glance but it's exactly the same. So my answer, in C code, would be:

```
int min_steps(n){
    return (n / 3) + (n % 3 > 0); // So it's n/3 with multiples of 3
                                  // n/3 + 1 otherwise
}
```

Edit: as [Eduardo León](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46571/eduardo-le%C3%B3n) commented, it can be reduced even further to:

```
    return (n + 2) / 3;
```

Comment: So, `(n + 2) / 3`, then?

Comment: `(5 + 2) / 3 = 7 / 3 = 2`

Comment: Beautiful, i don't even know what i was thinking with my previous comments xd but wasn't it `(n + 2)` instead of `(n + 3)`?

Comment: Err, yeah, sorry, I was careless.

Comment: @Emiliano Sorbello : Yeah I understand your solution. But may I know, how it works ? For eg., if the N is 4, then minimum no steps will be 2. How 4 cards can be flipped completely ? Could you please explain this ?

Comment: NovaDenizen explained the logic perfectly. My answer just gives the number of minimum flips assuming the cards are flipped following that logic

Answer (score 1):

```
(N - (N % 3)) / 3 + (N % 3 ? 1 : 0)
```

I have taken Higuaro's comment and have removed the need to round. This formula gives you the minimum number of turns for N cards as a whole number.

Answer (score 1):

I got the right answer with a perfect score. Here's the solution:-

```
if( n==1 || n ==2) return 1
else if( n%3 == 0) return n/3
else  return n
```

Just run through the combinations till n=7 or 8 and you will figure it out. The trick over here is to group 3 flip downs- figured out it in the hard way and a bit of mathematical induction helped.

Note:- I tried the rest of the solutions mentioned and it turned out to be wrong.

Comment: You are totally right. (n + 2) / 3 or N / 3 + (N % 3 ? 1 : 0) will not work.